# Obtaining library version when merging into single assembly

Tags: c#, assemblies, version

I have a desktop app that enables the user to run one of ten or so individual modules. Each module exists as an independent class library in the solution. Versioning of the individual modules is important to the user, so I want to be able to list the versions of each of the class libraries in the Help->About box. This is pretty straightforward, and I currently do it in by populating a richText box in the AboutBox using the snippet below.

```
this.moduleVersions.Text = "";
foreach (var kvp in mainform.moduleList)
    this.moduleVersions.Text += String.Format("{0,-20}: {1}\r\n", kvp.Key, kvp.Value.Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString());
```

Note that the list of modules in the parent main form is a dictionary of names and types:

```
public Dictionary<string, Type> moduleList = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
```

But here's the wrinkle. On a release build, I obfuscate and merge all the dll's into a single executable. Putting aside the question of whether or not this is best practice (I know it's not but there are compelling reasons for it), the problem is that it breaks the snippet above because now all the modules are physically in the same assembly (the parent main form), and they all return the main assembly's version. I want to somehow carry through the version numbers of the original assemblies. Is this possible without brute force (i.e. hard-coding version numbers)?

Also, I don't think it's relevant but I'm using .NET Reactor for the obfuscation and merging.

Thanks.

Comment: Create a custom attribute and decorate the types.

Comment: I posted it as an answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom attribute and decorate the types.